# API for getting American city, state information by a given zipcode

Tags: php

Any one know about any API which give city, state informations for a given zipcode.
There are  Database available for this.But i need an API

Comment: Yes, but not got a relevant one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the United States Postal Service provides [APIs](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the state only:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ZIP_code_prefixes

Answer (score 0):

you can use this API and give the ZIP code in $Zip now to can get the XML of that zip which included the city, State and etc...

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='.$Zip.'@&sensor=true'
```